# How to Display ListView, with 3 edit text stored on 3 columns on SQLite Database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, android-sqlite

I am trying to build an application where the user will enter 3 data on 3 edit texts which are then stored to 3 columns on the database. The user display them on a listview which allows them to select the whole item to edit either one of the text fields or delete the entire item as a whole. So far the adding of data to the database is still working, it is being stored to 3 different columns . As for the display, it only display the first edit text which is the first column of data in the database which is BodyTemp.

ViewRecords.java

```
package mdad.project;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.example.manandhowproject.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ViewRecords extends Activity {
    DatabaseHelper dbhelper;
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewrecords);

        dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        populateListView();
    }

    private void populateListView()
    {
        Cursor records = dbhelper.getRecords();
        ArrayList<String> listRec = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(records.moveToNext()){
            listRec.add(records.getString(1));
        }
    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listRec);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
             String BTemp = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
             String HRate = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
             String Bmi = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

             Cursor data = dbhelper.getRecID(BTemp, HRate, Bmi);
             int recID = -1;
             while(data.moveToNext()){
                 recID = data.getInt(0);
             }
             if(recID > -1){

                 Intent editScreenIntent = new Intent(ViewRecords.this, EditDel.class);
                 editScreenIntent.putExtra("id",recID);
                 editScreenIntent.putExtra("Body Temperature",BTemp);
                 editScreenIntent.putExtra("Heart Rate",HRate);
                 editScreenIntent.putExtra("BMI",Bmi);
                 startActivity(editScreenIntent);
             }
             else{
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No ID Associated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
         }
     });
 }}
```

DatabaseHelper.java

```
package mdad.project;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "medrec.db";
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "myrec_data";
        public static final String COL1 = "ID";
        public static final String COL2 = "BodyTemp";
        public static final String COL3 = "HeartRate";
        public static final String COL4 = "BMI";



     public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, 1);
        }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL2 + " TEXT, " + COL3 + " TEXT, " + COL4 + " TEXT);";
    db.execSQL(createTable);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade (SQLiteDatabase db,int i, int i1)
    {
         db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
         onCreate(db);
    }

     public boolean addRecord(String BodyTemp, String HeartRate, String BMI) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(COL2, BodyTemp);
            contentValues.put(COL3, HeartRate);
            contentValues.put(COL4, BMI);

            long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);


            if (result == -1) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }


     public Cursor getRecords()
     {
         SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
         String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
         Cursor records = db.rawQuery(query, null);
         return records;
     }

     public Cursor getRecID(String BTemp, String Hrate, String Bmi){
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            String query = "SELECT " + COL1 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
                    " WHERE " + COL2 + " = '" + BTemp + "AND" + COL3 + " = '" + Hrate + "AND" + COL4 + " = '" + Bmi +"'";
            Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
            return data;
        }

    public void updateBtemp(String bodytemp, int selectedID,
            String selectedBtemp) {
          SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
          String query = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET " + COL2 +
                    " = '" + bodytemp + "' WHERE " + COL1 + " = '" + selectedID + "'" +
                    " AND " + COL2 + " = '" + selectedBtemp + "'";
            db.execSQL(query);

    }

    public void updateHrate(String heartrate, int selectedID,
            String selectedHrate) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
          String query = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET " + COL3 +
                    " = '" + heartrate + "' WHERE " + COL1 + " = '" + selectedID + "'" +
                    " AND " + COL3 + " = '" + selectedHrate + "'";
            db.execSQL(query);

    }

    public void updateBMI(String bmi, int selectedID, String selectedBMI) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
          String query = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET " + COL4 +
                    " = '" + bmi + "' WHERE " + COL1 + " = '" + selectedID + "'" +
                    " AND " + COL4 + " = '" + selectedBMI + "'";
            db.execSQL(query);

    }

    public void deleteBtemp(int selectedID, String selectedBtemp) {
           SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            String query = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "
                    + COL1 + " = '" + selectedID + "'" +
                    " AND " + COL2 + " = '" + selectedBtemp + "'";

            db.execSQL(query);

    }

    public void deleteHrate(int selectedID, String selectedHrate) {
           SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            String query = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "
                    + COL1 + " = '" + selectedID + "'" +
                    " AND " + COL3 + " = '" + selectedHrate + "'";

            db.execSQL(query);

    }

    public void deleteBMI(int selectedID, String selectedBMI) {
           SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            String query = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "
                    + COL1 + " = '" + selectedID + "'" +
                    " AND " + COL4 + " = '" + selectedBMI + "'";

            db.execSQL(query);

    }

}
```

EditDel.java

```
package mdad.project;
import com.example.manandhowproject.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class EditDel extends Activity {

    Button btnSave,btnDelete;
    EditText etBT, etHR, etBMI;

    DatabaseHelper dbhelper;

    private String selectedBtemp, selectedHrate, selectedBMI;
    private int selectedID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.editdel);
        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
        etBT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etBT);
        etHR = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etHR);
        etBMI = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etBMI);
        dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);


        Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();


        selectedID = receivedIntent.getIntExtra("id",-1); 
        selectedBtemp = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("BTemp");
        selectedHrate = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("Hrate");
        selectedBMI = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("Bmi");



        etBT.setText(selectedBtemp);
        etHR.setText(selectedHrate);
        etBMI.setText(selectedBMI);

        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String bodytemp = etBT.getText().toString();
                String heartrate = etHR.getText().toString();
                String bmi = etBMI.getText().toString();
                if(!bodytemp.equals("") && !heartrate.equals("") && !bmi.equals("")){
                    dbhelper.updateBtemp(bodytemp,selectedID,selectedBtemp);
                    dbhelper.updateHrate(heartrate,selectedID,selectedHrate);
                    dbhelper.updateBMI(bmi,selectedID,selectedBMI);

                }else{
                    toastMessage("Please ensure all fields are filled.");
                }
            }
        });

        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               dbhelper.deleteBtemp(selectedID,selectedBtemp);
               dbhelper.deleteHrate(selectedID,selectedHrate);
               dbhelper.deleteBMI(selectedID,selectedBMI);
                etBT.setText("");
                etHR.setText("");
                etBMI.setText("");
                toastMessage("removed from database");
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * customizable toast
     * @param message
     */
    private void toastMessage(String message){
        Toast.makeText(this,message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variable name have to be same.

In **ViewRecords**, you set variable to

```
Intent editScreenIntent = new Intent(ViewRecords.this, EditDel.class);
editScreenIntent.putExtra("id",recID);
editScreenIntent.putExtra("Body Temperature",BTemp);
editScreenIntent.putExtra("Heart Rate",HRate);
editScreenIntent.putExtra("BMI",Bmi);
startActivity(editScreenIntent);
```

So in **EditDel**, you need to `getIntent` with same variable name

```
 selectedBtemp = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("Body Temperature");
 selectedHrate = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("Heart Rate");
 selectedBMI = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("BMI");
```

Comment: Hi now I am able to pass the values however, it seems that my other 2 edit texts are getting the same value from the 1st edit texts as well. Which is my main problem which is that on ViewRecords it only display the 1st column of database which is also the 1st edit text records, and not all 3 as I wanted. And also I realized not all records added are able to select. Some keep prompting 'No ID Associated' which was a check I did for when recID < -1 as shown on the code above. please advise. I really need help

Comment: you need to check why you will get `No ID Associated`. Did all values saved in database successfully?

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply, I was doing testings to find out why the No ID Associated occur. Ok apparently everytime when the 3 values are of different values for eg, 80/50/40 it will occur that message , No ID Associated. But if all 3 values are the same like80/80/80 then only I will be able to select it and delete or update. Also. If i changed 80/80/80 to 85/80/80 then after i update it. I cannot select it again, it will say No ID Associated. And btw, yes I have checked the database is working properly.

Comment: can you display the value of recID for `80/50/40`,  `80/80/80` and `80/50/80`  ?